# When the text already has line breaks, ellipsis does not appear

Tags: flutter, dart

Everything works fine only if there is only one paragraph of text.
However, when the text itself has line breaks and exceeds the
`maxLines`, Flutter does not automatically add an ellipsis.

Here is the common example code :

```
Text.rich(
 maxLines: 4,
 SoftWrap: true,
 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
 TextSpan(text: '''
1
2
3
4
5'''),
              ),
```

And it is what I get

[image: And it is what you get]

But I expected the 4 is followed by "..."

What are some ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What the Text's parent Widget is?

Comment: i found an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50168) which contains your problem, still open, perhaps there is no way to solve this problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsis only appears if the last available line of the `Text` widget actually overflows, meaning that no ellipsis is needed if the cutof line has enough space for it's content.

To solve it you can format the text to have an ellipsis and the right amount of lines to split into `Text` widgets or in whatever layout you want.

```dart
extension LineEllipsis on String {
  String take_lines_with_elipsis([int lines = 1]) {
    assert(lines >= 0);

    final text_lines = split('\n');

    // [sample_text] adds a '\n' at the end of every line,
    // but you may not add one always and if you don't care
    // use [trimRight] to just remove it
    final end_break = (endsWith('\n')) ? 1 : 0;

    if (text_lines.length - end_break > lines) {
      return [...text_lines.take(lines), '...'].join('\n');
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  String sample_text([int len = 100]) {
    var text = '';
    for (final char in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) {
      text += '${char * len}\n';
    }
    return text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
          Text.rich(
            maxLines: 2,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            TextSpan(text: sample_text()),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Text.rich(
            maxLines: 3,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            TextSpan(text: sample_text().take_lines_with_elipsis(2)),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Text.rich(
            maxLines: 3,
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            TextSpan(text: sample_text(10).take_lines_with_elipsis(2)),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ...sample_text()
              .split('\n')
              .map(
                (str) => Text.rich(
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  TextSpan(text: str),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          Divider(),
          ...sample_text()
              .take_lines_with_elipsis(3)
              .split('\n')
              .map(
                (str) => Text.rich(
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  TextSpan(text: str),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(App());
```